# Unable to read the json object stored in React state

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Quiz extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showInstruction: true,
            questionIndex: 0,
            isLoading: true,
            questions: ''
        };
    }

    proceedHandler = () => {
        this.setState({
            showInstruction: false
        })
    }

    handleQuestion = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('show next question');
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("After mount! Let's load data from API...");
        axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: "/apis/questions"
        }).then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
            this.setState({ questions: response.data });
            this.setState({ isLoading: false });
        });
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.showInstruction) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h1>Welcome to Quiz</h1>
                    <p>Quiz instructions goes here</p>
                    <button type="button" onClick={this.proceedHandler}>Proceed</button>
                </div>
            )
        }
        const { isLoading, questions } = this.state;
        console.log(this.state['questions'][0]);
        console.log(questions[0]);
        if (isLoading) {
            return <div className="App">Loading...</div>;
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    
                    <div onChange={this.onChangeValue}>
                        {/* {questions[0]} */}
                    </div>
                    <button onClick={this.handleQuestion}>Next</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Quiz;
```

My sample API content looks like the below. Right now making the api call to local file which is stored inside Public folder. Path is `public/apis/questions`.

```
[
    {
        id: 0,
        question: `What is the capital of Nigeria?`,
        options: [`New Delhi`, `Abuja`, `Aba`, `Onisha`],
        answer: `Abuja`
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        question: `What is the capital of India?`,
        options: [`Punjab`, `Awka`, `Owerri`, `Enugu`],
        answer: `New Delhi`
    }
]
```

I am building a quiz app and above is my code. I try to fetch the questions from api and render them one by one based on state. I am using axios to fetch the data inside componentDidMount and I can see the `this.state.questions` is updated with the questions array. But when I do `questions[0]` or `this.state.questions[0]`, it always returns `[`. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am fairly new the react development.

Comment: set `questions: []` instead of `questions: ''` in your `this.state`

Comment: Your code generally looks fine - here's a stackblitz showing your example with everything working as expected - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-7v2yrd?file=Quiz.tsx

Comment: response is string for some reason instead of JSON object. Try setting `headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}` in axios also check api is sending response in correct format. Else do `JSON.parse()` on the response to convert it to JSON object from string.

Comment: Thanks @ShivamJha and @gerrod. Even after changing the `questions: []`, its not working. Ofcourse it works if I do like this stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-7v2yrd?file=Quiz.tsx

Comment: @GauravVichare: Still getting `[` after adding headers.

Comment: `this.setState({ questions: JSON.parse(response.data) })`

Comment: Thanks @GauravVichare. It throws me console error `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 16
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)`

Comment: can you update the question with response returned by API? which technology used for backend API?

Comment: Thanks @GauravVichare. Updated the question. I am making api call to local file which is stored in `public/apis/question`. Later I will replace with a call from backend which will use PHP.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot with what `console.log(response.data);` returns in your componentDidMount and what `console.log(this.state.questions);` returns when called inside your render method?

Comment: Thank you everyone. I made a mistake in my api data. I missed to wrap the keys with double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is from my API data. I missed to wrap the keys with double quotes.
Updating the data from api call resolved my issue. So the sample api data will look like the below.

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "question": "What is the capital of Nigeria?",
        "options": [
            "New Delhi",
            "Abuja",
            "Aba",
            "Onisha"
        ],
        "answer": "Abuja"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "question": "What is the capital of India?",
        "options": [
            "Punjab",
            "Awka",
            "Owerri",
            "Enugu"
        ],
        "answer": "New Delhi"
    }
]
```